# Cycle symmetric Sort for arguments of a function. Put trace in canonical order

Tags: sorting, permutation

I need a new Sort for the arguments of TR that maintains cyclicity, TR[a,b,c] = TR[b,c,a] = TR[c,a,b]

```
cyclicSort[TR[b,a,c]]
```

> TR[a,c,b]

```
cyclicSort[TR[11,3,99,7]]
```

> TR[3,99,7,11]

Any ideas are useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
cyclicSort[TR[]] := TR[];
cyclicSort[TR[args__]] := RotateLeft[TR[args], Ordering[{args}, 1] - 1]
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Didn't remember the rotate functions. Much appreciated!

Comment: For reference: that definition does not treat cases like TR[a,c,a]. To also put the a's together, ```cyclicSort[TR[args__]] := Module[{aux = {args}},
  aux = RotateLeft[aux, Ordering[aux, 1] - 1];
  If[Order @@ aux[[{1, -1}]] == 0, aux = RotateRight[aux], {}];
  TR @@ aux]```